# How to sort list in R?

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have list of lists similar to this:

```
a <- list(
  list(day = 5, text = "foo"),
  list(text = "bar", day = 1),
  list(text = "baz", day = 3),
  list(day = 2, text = "quux")
)
```

with unknown number of fields and the fields my be out of order.

how can I sort this list based on day? I need the list to be sorted ascending. I've search but I only found how to sort vectors. Is it possible to sort a list?

Comment: `a[order(sapply(a, function(x) x$day))]`

Comment: `a[order(sapply(a, \`[[\`, i = "day"))]`

Comment: @UweBlock I'm using `sortBy <- function(a, field) a[order(sapply(a, `[[`, i = field))]` and got error `Error in order: unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'` the same is for @d.b solution

Comment: This? `a[order(sapply(a, unlist)[1,])]`

Comment: That's strange `sortBy <- function(a, field) a[order(sapply(a, "[[", i = field))]; sortBy(a, "day")` works for me.

Comment: @UweBlock yes it work with hat data, the problem may be in different place. You can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to sort that given "list of lists" `a` you can try to use `sapply()`with the extraction operator `[[` to retrieve data from the list. These are used in the call to `order()`:

```
a[order(sapply(a, `[[`, i = "day"))]
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$day
#[1] 1
#
#[[1]]$text
#[1] "bar"
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$day
#[1] 2
#
#[[2]]$text
#[1] "quux"
# ...
```

As suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477069/how-to-sort-list-in-r/43477738#comment74009525_43477069), this can also be achieved by using an *anonymous function* in `sapply()`:

```
a[order(sapply(a, function(x) x$day))]
```

This also works when used in a function definition as the OP did:

```
sortBy <- function(a, field) a[order(sapply(a, "[[", i = field))]
sortBy(a, "day")
```

Note that we need to enclose the extraction operator `[[` either in backquotes or quotes.