# Sorting a list of lists based on the third element

Tags: r, sorting

I've got an object names `x` which is a list containing inner lists.

```
`x$population`

output
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 11

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 20

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 2
```

I want to be able to sort the list based on the third elements: 
`x$population[[2]][[3]]` but I have no idea how to do it.

I have no idea how to start so instead of got some mock code that re-creates the problem:

```
z <- list() 

z[[1]] <- list(1, 10, 0.5) 
z[[2]] <- list(1, 10, 0.87)
```

How would I go about sorting z based on the third elements of each list (0.5, 0.87) such that the larger value is at the top.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort list in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477069/how-to-sort-list-in-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Pick out the third elements, get their order and subscript the list by that:

```
z[order(sapply(z, "[[", 3))]
```

**2)** Another approach is to represent the data as a matrix `a` and then sort that:

```
a <- sapply(z, unlist)
a[, order(a[3, ])]
```

Comment: `sapply` seems to do the trick and is nice and short. But thanks for also giving an alternate approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To do it explicitly: I would extract the third element and sort it.

I create a more complex list:

```
z <- list() 

z[[1]] <- list(1, 10, 0.5) 
z[[2]] <- list(1, 10, 0.87) 
z[[3]] <- list(1, 10, 0.2)
```

I extract third element of each element:

```
thirdelt <- sapply(z, function(x)x[[3]])
```

Then I sort it:

```
thirdelt_order <- order(thirdelt)
```

Finaly I apply it:

```
z <- z[thirdelt_order]
```